# Cannot use import alias in component tests

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm trying to use simple React component tests with WebdriverIO, Mocha and TypeScript. I met an issue specifically related to using import aliases in WebdriverIO.

I have simple template components and one of them imports another component using the alias:

```
// Comp1.tsx:
import Comp2 from '@app/components/comp2/Comp2';
```

So when I execute a test which just renders the component:

```
///  <reference types="@wdio/globals/types" />
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import Comp1 from '../src/components/Comp1'

describe('Test', () => {

  it('should render a component', async () => {
    render(<Comp1 />)
  })

})
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error:  Test failed due to the following error: [plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "@app/components/comp2/Comp2" from "src/components/Comp1.tsx". Does the file exist?
```

The imports in components are correct, the app can be started without errors so it's only an issue within the WebdriverIO configuration.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
    "@app/*": ["src/*"]
}
```

Here's a part of my `wdio.conf.ts`:

```
mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 6000000,
    // requireModule: ['tsconfig-paths/register']
  },
```

I found this article about using aliases in WebdriverIO and I tried to use the `tsconfig-paths/register` as advised [here](https://blog.emumba.com/how-to-use-alias-in-webdriverio-fe6530f9fe95).

When I uncomment the `requireModule` in `wdio.conf.ts`, I get an error:

```
TypeError: self[opt] is not a function\n' +
[0-0]         '    at http://localhost:51604/node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js:161:18\n'
```

**NOTE:** The error happens even when I don’t use any component imports, it’s just about the `requireModule: ['tsconfig-paths/register']` itself.

The project contains the following configs:
[image]

How to use import aliases with WebdriverIO? There's nothing in their documentation unfortunately.

UPD1: I've tried adding alias to the web pack config like this:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  alias: {
    "@app/*": ["src/*"],
  },
},
```

It didn't affect anything

Comment: Can you share your vite config file?

Comment: @eroironico there's no vite config in the project. I've updated the question with the screenshot of other available configs if it makes sense)

Comment: Ok i see, to me it seems like you're missing the [import aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve) in your webpack config

Comment: @eroironico I've tried adding the alias to the web pack config (updated the initial question) but it didn't help. I'm not sure this web pack config plays any role in the webdriverio component testing. Should it?

Comment: I don't have much experience with webpack, however I know that vite, without those alias, will throw that error and I thought the solution was similar. One last thing I can suggest is to check if `["src/*"]` is the right format or if it requires some path formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the vite config helped. I'm not sure why isn't it added with the wdio installation or at least not documented anywhere